# Elixir: unused variable name although its been used

Tags: elixir

```
 def build_map(script_str) do
    script_str = String.replace_leading(script_str ")", "")
    script_str = String.replace(script_str, "false", "111")
    script_str = String.replace(script_str, "null", "111")
    script_str = String.replace(script_str, "\'", "111")
    String.replace(script_str, ")", "")
end
```

opening an interactive shell via mix command `iex -S mix` gives the following error:

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: variable "script_str" is unused
  lib/moviematch.ex:21


== Compilation error in file lib/moviematch.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/moviematch.ex:22: undefined function script_str/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

I am new to elixir can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the first line of your function. Elixir tries to execute `script_str ")"` but can't find the `script_str` function and complains about it loudly.

Replace this

```
script_str = String.replace_leading(script_str ")", "")
```

With this

```
script_str = String.replace_leading(script_str, ")", "")
```

Also, see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54595181/1173020) with the function code rewritten to be more idiomatic for Elixir.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, mybad :)

Answer (score 4):

Posting this as an answer for the sake of formatting. **Please do not upvote.**

The whole function body is not an Elixir idiomatic code. That’s how we do write this in Elixir using [`Kernel.|>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) aka *pipe operator*:

```
def build_map(script_str) do
  script_str
  |> String.replace_leading(")", "")
  |> String.replace("false", "111")
  |> String.replace("null", "111")
  |> String.replace("\'", "111")
  |> String.replace(")", "")
end
```

That way you have fewer chances to make a mistake like the one you did.

Comment: Thanks for giving direction to a newbie. Is there any document that can refer for Elixir idiomatic code?

Comment: I am unsure if there is _the document_ (“idiomatic” is biased by default :). I would definitely go through all the chapters [here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html). Code snippets might shed a light on what we consider being a good code. Also, without solid understanding of how OTP works is makes a little sense to ever try Elixir. The reference I gave includes a great introduction into main OTP  principles.

Comment: Also this [style guide](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide) would be helpful too